# How do I connect SAMBA with a remote Print Server (i.e. Remote CUPS)?

Tags: samba, printing, remote

In this particular setup, SAMBA & CUPS run on **two different** servers, say *Server A* (for SAMBA) and *Server B* (for CUPS).

What I want to achieve is that print jobs coming from SAMBA users (Windows clients) should be handled by SAMBA Server (Server A) and then handed to CUPS Server (Server B) to be printed by the chosen printer.

How to interface this SAMBA Server (Server A) and CUPS Server (Server B)?

How to make printers (attached to Server B) visible via SAMBA?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using something like:

#### Printing

printcap name = cups
   printcap cache time = 300
   printing = cups
   load printers = yes
   cups server = cups01.srv.bevaix.stgraber.net